# ReactJS build is putting a '/' infront of every path, and it's making all css and images fail to load

Tags: html, css, reactjs, build, path

As shown in the linked image,

After running "npm run build", all of the paths begin with a "/", and this is the case for every single image and css link.

As soon as I remove the "/" it displays without a problem.

Why is it set to the wrong path, and how do I fix this? As I cannot find every item in the files.

[index.html with static paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfiui.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you hosting your app on a sublink? like `/something/app`? If so, take a look at [Serving the Same Build from Different Paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths)